Finding a mathematical description of the wavefunction without knowing the operator of the eigenfunctions
Suppose we have some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and a Hermitian operator acting on that space: $$\hat{f} |\psi_n\rangle = f_n |\psi_n\rangle $$
Then it is known (by the Spectral theorem?) that one can express every wavefunction in that Hilbert space as (Assuming it's discrete, it's a bound state):
$$|\Psi\rangle=\sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty c_n|\psi_n\rangle$$
For simplicity let's talk about the double-slit experiment; The electron passes through one of the two slits with some probability $|\alpha|^2$ or $|\beta|^2$, using the probabilistic nature of the wavefunction:
$$|\Psi\rangle=\alpha|\psi_1\rangle+\beta|\psi_2\rangle$$
Question
I want to approach it mathematically, without using the probabilistic interpretation, and I have no clue how to do it.
So far, I thought about the sum of states as a mathematical consequence.

Staying with that state of mind, how can I find some operator and its eigenfunctions, eigenvalues that correspond to this physical system?

Why does superposition hold here?



You want an operator whose eigenvectors are $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2 \rangle$? Is that what you mean? Anything of the form $a_1|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1\rangle + a_2|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2\rangle$, where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are real, will do, provided the two states are orthogonal.

You are correct that you can express a quantum state as a superpositon of eigenstates of a Hermitian operator, but that doesn't mean any superposition you can make arise from that. e.g., just take your $|\Psi\rangle=\sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty c_n|\psi_n\rangle$ and combine $c_0|\psi_0\rangle$ and $c_1|\psi_1\rangle$ into a new term $|\psi'\rangle=c_0|\psi_0\rangle+c_1|\psi_1\rangle$ so that now $|\Psi\rangle=|\psi'\rangle+\sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty c_n|\psi_n\rangle$ where $|\psi'\rangle$ is not a eigenstate of the operator that the $|\psi_n\rangle$'s are.
In the double slit case, we take $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$ to be states where $\langle x|\psi_n\rangle=\psi_n(x)$ take the shape of a Gaussian centered at the center of slit $n$ at some point in time. $|\Psi\rangle=\alpha|\psi_1\rangle+\beta|\psi_2\rangle$ is overall a linear combination of position eigenstates even if $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$ are not position eigenstates.
